# Show value of variable from json string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a for-loop:

```
var player = 5;
 for (var i = 0; i <10; i++) {
      $("#id").append('<div class="game_content_text">'+json_var[i].content+'</div>');
    }
```

The json looks like:

```
  "content":"<script>player</script>"
```

Now I only want to to write down the 5 but nothing  is showing...

Edit: I simplified it. Why I have to show more code? The problem is in this lines... 
For example if i show a simple text from the json ("content":"example!") it works...

For explanation:
I have a buck of personal questions in the JSON Feed. 
Example: "Hello 'name_variable' how are you?"

And in the the 'name_variable' i want show random names...

Comment: Missing quote in aperture of .append('

Comment: Why does your JSON have code in it, and why does that code do nothing (other than if `getrandomnumber` has side-effects)?

Comment: That's what i am asking now...

Comment: Show full code please.

Comment: A variable won't show by itself.

Comment: How to show then?

Answer (score 1):

If we append `script` tag dynamically then you need to call that code which is inside newly added script.
A script tag result cannot be assign a variable or it cannot be shown as result.

You can try following example

```
$(function(){   
    var test = "this.Foo = function() {alert('hi');}";
    var F=new Function (test);
    (new F()).Foo(); //Shows "Hi" alert
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to get more code simply for the fact that I can understand the context better, because your code is rather confusing.

So apparently you try to display the value player in all your appended elements?

```
var player = 5;
for (var i = 0, l = json_var.length; i < l; i++) {
    $("#id").append('<div class="game_content_text">' + player + '</div>');
}
```

Otherwise, if you really need that script to be stored in the json (for some reason). I'm assuming the class "game_content_text" is only used for this.

```
var player = 5;
for (var i = 0, l = json_var.length; i < l; i++) {
    $("#id").append('<div class="game_content_text">' + json_var[i].content + '</div>');
}

"content": "<script>$('.game_content_text').append(player);</script>"
```

I'm not all that familiar with jQuery, but that should work.
Also, I really do not recommend this.